# javascript not working in Pocket PC 2003 Emulator

Tags: asp.net, windows-mobile, emulation

I have developed a page in asp.net and it works fine in IE and firefox. Today i was testing it with Pocket PC 2003 emulator. I am using jQuery in that page to show/hide div on click of a link. It doesnt look like IE in the pocket PC 2003 emulator supports JavaScript. I also tried to display alert but no luck.

Is it correct assumption or am i missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if JavaScript is disabled in the emulator. You might install a power tool to be able to toggle JScript on/off.

It was called "Microsoft Internet Explorer Tools for Pocket PCs", or similar. Apparently not easily available on the Microsoft site.

[Internet Explorer Tools 1.0 at SoftPedia](http://handheld.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/Internet-Explorer-Tools-35706.shtml).

[image]

http://www.ppczone.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-14190.html

As for jQuery, it doesn't support IE 4.01. Here are some [discussions and workarounds for IE 4 on the jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/internet-explorer-version-4-what).

Only a subset of JavaScript is enabled here. What's being supported is [Microsoft's JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jscript).

Comment: Thanks its working now. But still my JQuery code is not running properly. Any ides what could be the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery doesn't support IE4.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Does it also not support SelectedIndexChanged event in dropdown? It seems i am either going the wrong path. What is the best way to develop mobile applications? Right now i am creating normal aspx pages. Is that not the right way?

Comment: I guess the question is now "what JavaScript is supported in IE 4.01 on Pocket PC 2003?" You'd probably get a better answer in a brand new question.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a new question.